# PickerView Remove Placeholder label swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, iqkeyboardmanager

Is there any way to remove `Select` string from top of the `UIPickerView` screen shot given below:

[image: Screen Shot]

Code:

```
var pickerVWUserList = UIPickerView() 

    //MARK:- Setup Picker View For TextField
func setupForPickerViewForTxtFld() {
    pickerVWUserList.delegate = self
    pickerVWUserList.dataSource = self
    txtfldAllGroup.inputView = pickerVWUserList
}

//MARK:- Extension for picker View
extension VC:UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return listOfAllTypesGroups.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return listOfAllTypesGroups[row].groupName
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    slctedGroupId = listOfAllTypesGroups[row].groupId
}
```

Thank you

Comment: how do you add UIToolbar in your code

Comment: please share your implementation for better expalanation

Comment: @emrcftci please check

Comment: @ShamDhiman - are you used inputAccessoryView for your txtfldAllGroup

Comment: make empty `UIToolbar` and set it to `pickerview`. first create a toolbar `let toolBar = UIToolbar()` then  `textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik no

Comment: @ShamDhiman - are you used the IQKeyboardmanager for your app

Comment: @ShamDhiman are you using IQKeyboardManager?

Comment: @yes i m using IQKeyboardManager

Comment: @ShamDhiman - you want to disable the placeholder only for picker view or else.

Comment: @ShamDhiman try my answer down

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes

Comment: @ZainAnjum okay i will

Comment: @ShamDhiman Please mark my answer as solved if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
     IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldShowToolbarPlaceholder = false

     return true
 }
```